# SQL Server: Return Only Rows Which Have Never Met A Given Criteria Across Multiple Rows

Tags: sql-server

Apologies for the vague title, this one was difficult to quantify in a single sentence.

For example: We have a very basic SQL table for version controlled defects. Each row in the table is a revision of a defect. A defect may have multiple revisions;

Columns are: DefectID, Revision, Synopsis, Tested

I'd like to select only defects which have never had a Tested value of 1 in *any* of their revisions.

I have a rough inkling that this might involve cursors or nested select statements, but honestly have no clue how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DefectId, sum(Tested)
from table
group by DefectId
having sum(tested) = 0
```

Cheers -

Comment: for the elegant solution.

Comment: What if `tested` is not numeric or contains values other than 0 or 1?

Comment: Even if it's not the case now, in the future a -1 might be used to represent something untestable. Your query can break if data that is irrelevant to the original question gets added to the table later. It's a bad practice to SUM() columns that don't represent an amount.

Comment: I assumed that it was a bit datatype. That's only going to be 0 or 1. And I don't agree it's a bad practice to sum non-amounts; usually doing so ends up meaning nothing but that's not true in this case.

Comment: You can't `SUM()` a `bit` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DefectId
from table
where DefectId not in (select DefectId
                       from table
                       where Tested = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The plain-English answer: "show me all the DefectIDs except the ones that have ever been tested".

```
SELECT DefectID FROM Defects
EXCEPT
SELECT DefectID FROM Defects WHERE Tested = 1
```